# Layout issue with iPhone X

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, iphone-x

When I am running my project in iPhone X simulator there is a black padding on top and bottom. I tried to add a safe layout guide and adjusted the view constraints as well but I'm still facing the same issue. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

[image: black padding on iPhone X]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Proper launch image sizes for iphone x should be provided. So the screen will render properly.